# With Tkinter grid method, i want to center the labels

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, center

When i use the grid method, the text is not well centered.

In the exemple below, i would like to get the labels "row 0 col 0" and "row 0 col 1" well centered.

Here is an example :

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI(tk.Tk):
   
    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="frame #1")
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.l1f1 = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="vvvvvvvvvveeeeeeeerrrryyyyyy "
                             "llllllllooooonnnngggg tttttteeeeeexxxxxxtttttt")
        self.l1f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="frame #2")
        self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        
        self.l1f2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="  row 0 col 0  ")
        self.l1f2.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.l2f2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="  row 0 col 1  ")
        self.l2f2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.update()
        
        
mygui = GUI()
mygui.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to use `.grid_columnconfigure()` on Frame #2 - give each column a nonzero `weight=`, so that the grid will know where you want extra space to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using this method

```
grid_columnconfigure(index, weight)
```

Setting the weight to "1", the column will use the whole available width.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
   
    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="frame #1")
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.l1f1 = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="vvvvvvvvvveeeeeeeerrrryyyyyy "
                             "llllllllooooonnnngggg tttttteeeeeexxxxxxtttttt")
        self.l1f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="frame #2")
        self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        
        self.l1f2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="  row 0 col 0  ")
        self.l1f2.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.l2f2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="  row 0 col 1  ")
        self.l2f2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.update()        
        
mygui = GUI()
mygui.mainloop()
```

[image: columns now use the whole available width]